# How to integrate ESLint with Visual Stusio 2013?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, visual-studio, eslint

I need to configure ESLint in my Visual Studio 2013 angular js SPA application. 
Please help me on this.

Comment: I have searched the internet for days, no available extension found. The closest one is [JSLint for Visual Studio 2013](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-283515.JSLintNETforVisualStudio#overview)

Answer (score -1):

[Web Essentials](http://vswebessentials.com) extends Visual Studio with a lot of new features that web developers have been missing for many years.

If you ever write CSS, HTML, JavaScript, TypeScript, CoffeeScript or LESS, then you will find many useful features that make your life as a developer easier.

This is for all Web developers using Visual Studio.

Comment: is it possible to configure ES lint with this?

Comment: ESLint used in web development, Web essentials enhance web development, guess does it support ESlint?